# SELECT returns updated value during SELECT - UPDATE transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a SQL query that selects a serial number and then immediately increments the serial number. Problem is when I run the statement the select returns the updated serial number after the increment. I would expect it to return the serial number before the update then the update executes and sets the new serial number.

Below is the SQL:

```
 START TRANSACTION;

  -- Let's get the current value
  SELECT serial FROM boxLabelSerial FOR UPDATE;

   -- Increment the counter
  UPDATE boxLabelSerial SET serial = serial + 1;

  COMMIT;
```

Thank You.

Comment: Use `identity`.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: A good overview of this is available on DBA SE http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46459/putting-a-select-statement-in-a-transaction

Answer (score 1):

But, if you are going to re-invent the wheel, you need to "carry" the value from tone statement to the other.  A variable is one way to do this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

  -- Let's get the current value
  SELECT @s := serial FROM boxLabelSerial FOR UPDATE;

   -- Increment the counter
  UPDATE boxLabelSerial SET serial = @s + 1;

COMMIT;
```

Note:  your approach only works if you assume that `boxLabelSerial` has exactly one row.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I ran the above statement but it still returned the updated serial, there is only one unique row in this table. I wasn't quiet sure what you meant by identity? There is a unique ID on the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE boxLabelSerial SET LAST_INSERT_ID(serial) = serial + 1;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FOR UPDATE;

COMMIT;
```